# how to update a single field value?

Tags: sql, vb6

I use a MS Access database and the table stock having fields:

- brand name
- model name
- stock

Now I want to update the stock value of a particular product. I have two input boxes for this purpose.

I use the code below.

```
Private Sub cmddelstock_Click()
 Dim a As String
 Dim b As Integer
 a = InputBox("ENTER THE MODEL NAME HERE")
 b = Val(InputBox("ENTER NEW STOCK VALUE OF THE MODEL"))
 Adodc1.RecordSource = "UPDATE stock SET Stock='b' where Model_Name='a' "
 Adodc1.Refresh
```

The error I am experiencing is the syntax error in from clause.
I don't connect to the database via code, instead I connect to it via right click then go to properties. There I use connection string=microsoft jet oledb 4.0

then in record source tab command `type=1-adcmd type`

I perform UPDATE stock

Now what should I use in command text?

Answer (score 0):

The .RecordSource property is is just that: *The source from which the ADODBGrid is filled*. So, you cannot use this property to issue an `Update`SQL command (which by the way has some syntax errors of itself).

You need to put the SQL string in some kind of .Execute Sub of the class that handles the underlying data.

I am not familiair with ADO (I use DAO exclusively), but in DAO this would look like

```
dbStockDatabase.Execute "UPDATE Stock SET Stock.Stock=" & b & " WHERE Stock.Model_Name='" & a & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

in this syntax :

```
Adodc1.RecordSource = "UPDATE stock SET Stock='b' where Model_Name='a' "
```

a and b is not variabel but its character, change it to this :

```
"UPDATE stock SET Stock='" & b & "' where Model_Name='" & a & "'"
```